# Single number set problem

Tags: combinatorics

I can´t solve this problem and I will appreciate any help.

Given a set with N (N >= 1) distinct natural numbers. In each step we increase the lowest number by 2 and for every other number X we add X+1 to the set. Then, we replace each pair X,X with X+1 until all numbers in the set are distinct.

Prove that after finite number of steps we end up with a set that has only a single number.

Example:

A = {1,2,5,6,7,10}

Increase the lowest number by 2.

A = {3,2,5,6,7,10}

For every other number X we add X+1 to the set.

A = {3,2,2+1,5,5+1,6,6+1,7,7+1,10,10+1}

A = {2,3,3,5,6,6,7,7,8,10,11}

We replace each pair X,X with X+1.

A = {2,4,5,7,8,8,10,11}

We again replace each pair X,X with X+1.

A = {2,4,5,7,9,10,11} (after first step)

Comment: What do you do if you have thee of a number? If you start with 1,2,3 you go to 3,2,3 and then 3,2,3,3,4 which is 2,3,3,3,4 and then? To 2,3,4,4 or to 2,4,4?

Comment: You can only use 2 same numbers, so 2,3,3,3,4 => 2,3,4,4 => 2,3,5

Comment: The usual way to prove things like this is to find some quantity that always decreases until you get to a single number.  We certainly can't use the number of numbers.  I thought about the range from top to bottom but that doesn't work either.